# Dynamic Json Keys IE11 support

Tags: javascript

Apologies in advance if I am using the wrong words, but the issue I am having is related to IE11 and not being able to parse a dynamic JSON key. The reason it needs to be dynamic is because the ID's change environment to environment. for example, I have the following gets within my config.js file (abbreviated)

```
categories: {
        clientCommon: {
            get FirstName() {
                var field = window.iqbg.common.staticStrings.fieldNotSetString;
                switch (window.iqbg.config.getCurrentEnvironment()) {
                    case 'debug':
                        field = "65638_27";
                        break;
                    case 'dev':
                        field = "341840_3";
                        break;
                }
                return field;
            },
            get LastName() {
                var field = window.iqbg.common.staticStrings.fieldNotSetString;
                switch (window.iqbg.config.getCurrentEnvironment()) {
                    case 'debug':
                        field = "65638_26";
                        break;
                    case 'dev':
                        field = "341840_2";
                        break;
                }
                return field;
            },
        }
    }
```

Then, in my main function, I leverage the following line of code:

```
  copyHHSFolders: function (firstName, lastName, clientType, dateOfBirth, callback) {
 var attributes = { [config.categories.clientCommon.FirstName]: firstName,
    [config.categories.clientCommon.LastName]: lastName, 
    [config.categories.clientCommon.DateOfBirth]: dateOfBirth };
    //turns into/IE version
    var attributes = { "341840_3": "Nick",
        "341840_2": "P",
        "341840_5": "1970-01-01" };
```

This then gets passed to an ajax call and does it's thing. Works fine in Chrome and firefox, but client is oldschool government and only supports IE11 (not Edge, but works there too)

However, IE11 likes to throw a javascript error when loading the above script. I did a manual fix right now by placing the actual item within brackets, but I don't want to have to do a find/replace every time I modify the code and move between environments.

Is there a better way to accomplish my goal? Note: lets keep it simple and say i'm only using abusing Visual Studio as a simple text editor to modify html/js at the current time, nothing like react/node/angular etc. only jquery/bootstrap/lodash and some other minor helper libraries.

I am not doing any type of ant compiling at the moment to do a find/replace of variables (did that on a previous project) but also unsure if that is the solution, or if something like leveraging a .ts instead of js. Again, apologies for my ignorance of these technologies, hard to stay on top of things.

Comment: if you have to support IE11 and don't want to use a compiler, then just don't use that syntax.. it's only sugar.

Comment: hi azium, how would you suggest to maintain this between environments though, I don't want to keep 4 copies of code. Any suggested compiler?

Comment: babel is the only compiler you'll ever need.. though you don't need to use a compiler. you can just not use the shorthand dynamic syntax. you can use es5 dynamic syntax like javascript used for 10 years, long before IE11, and it will work on every browser

Answer (score 0):

To others who are looking for an answer to this, azium's comments led me to the following (below) Basically, the shorthand for creating the object inline did not work. I did take the following approach which did.

```
//below line not IE compatible
//var attributes = { [config.categories.clientCommon.FirstName]: firstName, [config.categories.clientCommon.LastName]: lastName, [config.categories.clientCommon.DateOfBirth]: dateOfBirth };
//however, this is
var attributes = {};
attributes[config.categories.clientCommon.FirstName] =  firstName;
attributes[config.categories.clientCommon.LastName] = lastName;
attributes[config.categories.clientCommon.DateOfBirth] = dateOfBirth;
```